# shared libraries and visibility to user's memory

Tags: c, unix, shared-libraries

When I use a shared library via `dlopen`, can the library code "see" memory of my process that calls `dlopen`? For example, I would like to pass a pointer to memory  allocated by my application to the library API.

I'm on Linux/x86 if it is important.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, it can.  Here is a simple quick example for illustration purposes.

The library code (in file `myso.c`):

```
void setInt( int * i )
{
   *i = 12345;
}
```

The library can be built as follows:

```
gcc -c -fPIC myso.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy.so -o libmy.so myso.o -lc
```

Here is the client code (`main.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void (*setint_t)( int * );

int main()
{
  void * h = dlopen("./libmy.so", RTLD_NOW);
  if (h)
  {
    puts("Loaded library.");
    setint_t setInt = dlsym( h, "setInt" );
    if (setInt) {
      puts("Symbol found");
      int k;
      setInt(&k);
      printf("The int is %d\n", k);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now build and run the code.  Make sure main.c and the library are in the same directory, in which we execute the following:

```
user@fedora-21 ~]$ gcc main.c -ldl
[user@fedora-21 ~]$ ./a.out
Loaded library.
Symbol found
The int is 12345
```

As one can see, the library was able to write to the memory of the integer `k`.